# By contradiction. Prove that for any $ n > 0$, if $ a^n $ is even, then a is even.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

My proof goes something like this.

It says on the notes that this can be proved by contradiction, so I tried.

If P, then not(Q).
Assume $a$ is odd and $a^n$ is even. So $a = 2j + 1$.
Then $ a^n = (2j+1)^n$.

Say $n=1$, then it follows that $ a^1 = (2j+1)^1 = 2j + 1$ which is a contradiction because $a^n$ must be even. Therefore $a$ must also be even.

Is this a valid proof when I only considered n=1 ? Or is my reasoning valid at all? I followed what I read that when you are trying to prove an implication $P ⇒Q $  by contradiction, then you must assume its negation $\lnot(P ⇒ Q)$ which is also equivalent to $ P \land \lnot Q $.

Gracias!

Comment: You are asked to prove for any $n>0$.  Assume $a$ is odd.  Then $a^n$ is odd.  That proves the contrapositive. Or you could prove directly:  if $2$ divides $a^n,$ then $2$ divides $a$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not a valid proof since you only consider a special case. If you want to prove it by contradiction, suppose that $a$ is odd and $a^n$ is even (the negation of $P\Longrightarrow Q$). Then by [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma), since $2\mid a^n,$ and $2\nmid a,$ $2$ must divide $a^{n-1},$ then you keep applying the same process and reach a contradiction; strictly speaking, this is induction on $n.$

Comment: Question: Is this what mathematicians call "Without loss of generality"?

Comment: Not really, because I'm not assuming anything but the "oddness" of $a$

Comment: Sorry should have clarified, I meant the OP's "proof"

Answer (score 1):

What you were meant to prove was that if $a^n$ is even, then $a$ is even. If you prove it for $n=1$ only, then you shall have proved that if $a$ is even, then $a$ is even, which is a tautology anyway.

If $a$ is odd, then $a=2l+1$ for some integer $l$. But then $a^n=(2l+1)^n$. Now, by applying the binomial theorem, you can write $(2l+1)^n$ as $2L+1$ for some integer $L$. Therefore, $a^n$ is odd.